# I can't use my functions that i created in my .ts

Tags: ionic2

hi I'am new in ionic and i working with ionic 2. my problem is :
I have  write the functions in my about.ts this function run well (i have test this in the constructor of the page) but when i call this in about.html, nothing of this functions run. (sorry i don't speak english well)

that is my about.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Contacts, Contact} from 'ionic-native';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
//, ContactField
@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.html'
})
export class AboutPage {
  private customColor:string[] = ["#f44336", "#3f51b5", "#2196f3", "#009688", "#4caf50"];
  // index qui nous permet de changer de couleur
  private indexColor:number = 0;

  // les contactes trouvés
  public allContacts:Contact[];

  public findItem:string;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
    this.findContact('');
    this.openModal();
  }
  /** Suppression d'un contact */
  public delete(contactToDelete:Contact):void{
    contactToDelete.remove().then(()=>this.findContact(''));
  }


  public getCustomColor():string{
    let color:string = this.customColor[this.indexColor];
    this.indexColor++;

    if(this.indexColor === 5){
      this.indexColor = 0;
    }
    return color;
  }

  /** Ouverture de la modale pour la création de contact */
  public openModal():void{

    //let modal = Modal.create(CreateContact);

   // this._navController.present(modal);

   // modal.onDismiss(data => {
   //   this.allContacts.push(data);
   // });
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'soty',
      subTitle: 'rost',
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present();
  }


  /** Méthode pour effectuer la recherche de contact */
  public findContact(value:any){
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: value,
      subTitle: value,
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present();
    let fn = value === undefined ? '' :value;

     Contacts.find(['displayName', 'phoneNumbers'], {
      filter:fn,
      hasPhoneNumber:true
    }).then(data => {
      this.allContacts = data;

    });

  }

  /** Création des initiales sur 2 lettres */
  public getCustomInitial(value):string{
    let names:string[] = value.split(' ');

    let firstName = '';
    let secondName = '';

    if(names[0] != undefined){
      firstName = names[0].substring(0,1);
    }

    if(names[1] != undefined){
      secondName = names[1].substring(0,1);
    }
    return firstName + secondName;
  }
}
```

that is my about.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Gestion des contacts
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons start>
      <button (click)="openModal()">
        <ion-icon ios="ios-add" md="md-add"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding class="page1">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input
      type="text"
      placeholder="rechercher"
      [(ngModel)]="findItem"
      (Change)="findContact($event)"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let contact of allContacts">
      <ion-item class="bloc-contact">
        <ion-avatar item-left>
          <span
            class="initial" [style.background] = "getCustomColor()">
              {{ getCustomInitial(contact.displayName) }}
          </span>
        </ion-avatar>
        <h2>{{contact.displayName}}</h2>
        <div *ngFor="let phone of contact.phoneNumbers">

          <ion-item *ngIf="phone.type == 'mobile'" class="line">
            <ion-icon ios="ios-phone-portrait" md="md-phone-portrait"></ion-icon>
            Mobile
            <ion-badge teal item-right>{{phone.value}}</ion-badge>
          </ion-item>

          <ion-item *ngIf="phone.type == 'home'" class="line">
            <ion-icon ios="ios-home" md="md-home"></ion-icon>
            Home
            <ion-badge green item-right>{{phone.value}}</ion-badge>
          </ion-item>

        </div>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item-options>

        <button danger (click) = "delete(contact)">
          <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
          Delete
        </button>
      </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>

  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

somebody can help me please

Comment: which function?

Comment: openModal() and findContact()

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem with openModal() and the way you call it; but you must use this for your input event:

```
<ion-input type="text" placeholder="rechercher" [(ngModel)]="findItem" (input)='findContact($event.target.value)'>
```